# Azure function C#: Writing to Block blob (csv file) on Azure Storage Account creates two versions of the blob

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

On Azure Storage Account I have "Enabling versioning for blobs" enabled under Data protection.
Writing to Block blob (csv file) creates two versions, one with size "-" when the function is triggered and one with the actual file size when the function completed.

```
public class ReportTimerTrigger01
    {
        [FunctionName("ReportTimerTrigger01")]
        public async Task Run(
            [TimerTrigger("%schedule%")] TimerInfo myTimer,
            [Blob("%outputFile%", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
                Stream outputFile,
            ILogger log
        )
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            // Connect client with user assigned managed identity.
            
            
            StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
            sbResult.AppendLine("Hello world file content");
            
            UnicodeEncoding uniencoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
            string messageToWriteToFile = sbResult.ToString();
            byte[] output = uniencoding.GetBytes(messageToWriteToFile);
            await outputFile.WriteAsync(output, 0, output.Length);
        }

    }
```

How to create only one version after completion? Please consider that the actual content might be over 20 MB.
Thanks

Comment: "How to create only one version after completion?" - Don't enable "Enabling versioning for blobs" !!

Answer (score 0):

I assume (without having tested it), that the binding does in fact create an empty blob to start with, when the Function executes, even before you write to it. If disabling versioning is not an option for you, you might have better luck by binding to the `BlobContainerClient`. Then you can manually create your blob and write to it directly. This should only create one version.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/storage/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Blobs#accessing-blob-container

(but why is the empty version a problem for you in the first place?)